# How to stretch label over a custom div to achieve radio button click

Tags: css, radio-button, label

I'm trying to make a custom radio button. I've found [this](http://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/pen/Eypnq) neat style which I want to tweak a bit so that items are laid out horizontally.Consider the following html:

```
<div style="margin-left:30px;">
  <div class='container'>
<input type="radio" id="rdArts" name="itemcat">
    <label for="rdArts">Arts</label>    
    <div class="check"></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type="radio" id="rdElectronics" name="itemcat">
    <label for="rdElectronics">Electronics</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type="radio" id="rdCars" name="itemcat">
    <label for="rdCars">Cars</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
</div>
  </div>
```

and this css:

```
.container{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin-right:20px;
}

.container input[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.container label{
  display: block;
  position: ;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
.container:hover label{
    color: #485776;
}

.container:hover .check{
    border-color: #485776;
}

.container:hover .check::border{
    background-color: #485776;
}
.container .check{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #333E54;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: -67px;
  left: -25px;
    z-index: 5;
    transition: border .25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;  
}

.container .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
    content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  top: 2px;
    left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
    transition: background 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #333E54;
}
```

I am able to get this:

[image]

The only problem is I cannot get click to work on the pseudo radio button itself. I need to click on the label. And the reason is because in my case, label does not stretch over to the ".check" div. What style should I give to my label to make it overlay the div? If you want to see the full html and css,[here](http://codepen.io/mikayil/pen/WwdJMq) it is.

Comment: Just put the inputs inside the labels.

Comment: @MrLister, I know that is another way of achieving checkbox or radiobutton click when the corresponding label is clicked. In that case you don't have to specify the "for" attribute. But if you take a look at my html, you'll see that I'm hiding the actual radio and imitating its click with another  div element.

Comment: So put both the inputs AND the .checks inside the labels. [Here, a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/9hy9j12k/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working:

I slightly edited the `.container label` style to move a bit to the left to be above the checkbox images.

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin-right:20px;
}

.container input[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.container label{
  display: block;
  position: ;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
      margin: 10px auto 10px -26px;
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 36px;
    position: relative;
}
.container:hover label{
    color: #485776;
}

.container:hover .check{
    border-color: #485776;
}

.container:hover .check::border{
    background-color: #485776;
}
.container .check{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #333E54;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: -67px;
  left: -25px;
    z-index: 5;
    transition: border .25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;  
}

.container .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
    content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  top: 2px;
    left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
    transition: background 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #333E54;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:30px;">
  <div class='container'>
<input type="radio" id="rdArts" name="itemcat">
    <label for="rdArts">Arts</label>    
    <div class="check"></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type="radio" id="rdElectronics" name="itemcat">
    <label for="rdElectronics">Electronics</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type="radio" id="rdCars" name="itemcat">
    <label for="rdCars">Cars</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see the differences in the label style, but could you please explain why it workedthis way? BTW, I've corrected the for property of the arts label, so you can remove that notice.

Comment: What i basicly did is to move the labels slightly to the left to contain the checkbox image. If you look into the code you will notice that the labels now have a negativ margin to the left... I hope this is clear enough :)

Comment: The to achieve what I want, I needed to give it a negative left margin

Comment: If you don't want to make changes to the html, yes. Otherwise look into the solution from @MrLister